# jquery.dataTables.editable.js Version 2.3.3 Adding Record gives error at line 398 oAddNewRowForm has no "valid" property

Tags: jquery

I using jquery.datatables.editable.js which is working for delete and Update.  However, when I try to add a new record I get this message when I try to commit the form that adds the new row.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: add the message as well...

Comment: Got the answer: Issue 114 attachment: fixAddData.diff (2.1 KB)
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/

I've applied the patch and it's now working....

Comment: you should add an answer to your own question and mark it answered if that fixed your issue

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens mainly in the fnTakeRowDataFromFormElements function.
The column names are not retrieved properly for the rowData object at the following line, due to using mDataProp instead of mData.

```
rowData[oSettings.aoColumns[rel].mDataProp] = sCellValue;
```

I have updated this row to

```
rowData[oSettings.aoColumns[rel].mData] = sCellValue;
```

I also updated the section in fnOnRowAdded from

```
var values = fnTakeRowDataFromFormElements(oAddNewRowForm);
```

to

```
var rowData = fnTakeRowDataFromFormElements(oAddNewRowForm);
var rtn;
.... //removed the if statement in between
rtn = oTable.fnAddData(rowData);
```

there is a lengthy discussion at https://github.com/moksamedia/jquery-datatables-editable/issues/114 however be careful that 'data' variable contains the id returned from the db. some answers incorrectly reference that variable, ignore those. I have mainly used the patch that was in one of the answers.